# How to combine an R script and R markdown into one file?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am making a Shiny app to keep track of some things that need to be done at work. One component of the app is to send an email letting everyone know what they are responsible for doing that week. I originally wrote the code to do that in two separate pieces, an R markdown file to generate the emails, and an R script to iterate through a table that has user's names in it to generate a personalized email that includes the tasks for which they are responsible. Locally, this works fine. I have a button setup to run the R script, which then sources the R markdown code for each user and sends an email to each user. After deploying the app this no longer works. Debugging the Shiny app has proved tricky, but I'm guessing is has to do with the fact that the R script and R markdown file are not communicating with each other. I was wondering if I could solicit some advice on how to resolve this. Thank you in advance for any insight or advice, I only program a little for work and have been struggling to fix this. The code below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to use.

```
#DATA
email.addresses <- data.frame(user = as.character(c("Peyton Mannning", "John Elway")),
                              email.address = as.character(c("Peyton.manning@gmail.com", "john.elway@gmail.com")),
                              stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
email.complete <- data.frame(task = as.character(c("Do the dishes", "Mop the floor")), next.completion = as.Date("2020-12-10"), Responsible.Persons = as.character(c("Peyton Manning", "John Elway")))
```

```
#R script
library(lubridate)
library(blastula)
for (user in unique(email.addresses$User)){
  email <- render_email("email markdown.Rmd")
  email %>%
    smtp_send(
      from = "personal@email.net",
      to = email.addresses$Email[email.addresses$User == user],
      subject = paste("Cleaning Schedule for", floor_date(Sys.Date() - 1, "weeks") + 1, sep = " ", collapse = NULL),
      credentials = creds_key(id = "gmail")
    )
}
```

````
# markdown
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
email.complete.user <- email.complete[email.complete$Responsible.Persons == user,]
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
email.complete.user %>%
  kbl(row.names = FALSE, col.names = c("Task", "Completion Deadline", "Responsible User"), format = "html", table.attr = "style='width:100%;'", longtable = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", position = "left"), font_size = 20) %>%
  kable_minimal()```
````

Comment: Why don't you add the code in R script to R markdown? Open a code chunk and copy above the code in R Markdown.

Comment: @MehmetYildirim Thank you for your response. I made an attempt at that but couldn't get it to work since render_email uses the email markdown.rmd file. I tried putting the r markdown code inside of render_email but that didn't work either.